# Fantasy book where girl speaks with animals on an island kingdom

Tags: story-identification, books, young-adult

I've searched for hours trying to find a fantasy series and need help. It was published around 2016/2017 and is part of a series that is about 4 books long.

It takes place on different islands or around different islands. The protagonist is a princess whose parents are assassinated.

She goes into hiding with a foster family. She learns she can speak with animals by talking to horse (no dragons involved). In the second book, she's involved with a warrior.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Do you happen to recall the cover art?  The names of any of the characters or the islands?

Comment: I don't know either unfortunately. I am a librarian asking on behalf of a patron.

Answer (score 3):

Could this be [*A Queen in Hiding*](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/45046606) (2020) by Sarah Kozloff? It was a series of four books that were published within a year of each other. The protagonist is a princess who goes into hiding with a foster family. While in exile she learns that she can grunt and squeak and squawk with the animals.

> Orphaned, exiled and hunted, Cérulia, Princess of Weirandale, must
> master the magic that is her birthright, become a ruthless guerilla
> fighter, and transform into the queen she is destined to be.
>
> But to do it she must win the favor of the spirits who play in mortal
> affairs, assemble an unlikely group of rebels, and wrest the throne
> from a corrupt aristocracy whose rot has spread throughout her
> kingdom.
>
> [image]

She first learns of her ability while talking to her horse, something dismissed as childish fancy by her elders.

> “She’s got a good ear for music,” said Cressa. “But, we discussed this
> last year and I’ve paid close attention ever since; music may be a
> comfort in her life, but not a magical Talent.”
>
> “I can talk to my horse?” Cerúlia offered hesitantly.

Comment: I’ll offer it to my patron and see what she says. Thank you for your input and research!